# How to add changes to lambda using claudiajs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, claudiajs

I am using claudia js to deploy code in lambda using serverless framework.I run this claudia generate-serverless-express-proxy --express-module app which creates a lambda.js file and claudia create --handler lambda.handler --deploy-proxy-api --region eu-central-1 which deploys my api code in lambda.Now if there is a change in code how do I deploy that change in lambda?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run the `update` command.

Eg.

```
claudia update --version development --config frankfurt_claudia.json
```

This would give you the link to your tag lambda function, something like `<lambda-url>/development` in this case.

You can [check the whole set of options you can provide to the update command](https://github.com/claudiajs/claudia/blob/master/docs/update.md).